# css to Align icon on same line as menu items

Tags: menu, icons, alignment, spacing

I am working on this page right now http://www.ecovitalcostarica.com/ecoparadise-surf-school in wordpress and added a flag icon in the menu bar but it comes to the second line and I need it center align to the other items right after the last menu option (book now). with some nice spacing after last option. Is there a way to do this? thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to do a couple of things to improve this question: 1 - improve the title to make it more specific.  Is this related to HTML?  2 - Don't link to your code in an external website.  That may change, and SO has no control over that.  Paste the relevant code into your question so we can see it here.

Comment: hi! I edited the title to specify that it is related to css. But I can not find the exact code I need to edit :(
I usually view it in chrome - inspect element. Do you think no one will be able to help by looking at this? I did not created the page, but the menu won´t change anymore.
 I am taking over and as you see I do not know a lot about css. Thanks